# Nunit 3.12.0 missing [RequiresSTA] in WPF view model unit test. The calling thread must be STA

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, nunit

After update Nunit from version v2.6.3 to 3.12.0. my unit stopped passing.
The problem occurs in unit tests with RequiresSTAAttribute witch could not be found after update.

```
[Test]
[RequiresSTA]
public void When_Smart_Motion_Activity_Is_Selected_The_Values_Are_Valid()
{
     SomeViewModel vm = ViewModelHelper.CreateDefaultViewModel();
     ...
}
```

With attribute removed test failed with following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException : The calling thread must be STA,
>   because many UI components require this.    at
>   System.Windows.Input.InputManager..ctor()    at
>   System.Windows.Input.InputManager.GetCurrentInputManagerImpl()    at
>   System.Windows.Input.KeyboardNavigation..ctor()    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FrameworkServices..ctor()    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.EnsureFrameworkServices()    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement..ctor()    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Panel..ctor()    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Canvas..ctor()    at project..... :line xyz

Is there any suggested workaround or replacement for [RequiresSTA] that works for 3.12.0 ?

Comment: As a workaround I've added a new project. Now I have v2.6.3 with old Unit tests and new 3.12.0 with new tests. But this is not a solution for a question I've asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
[Test]
[Apartment(ApartmentState.STA)]
public void When_Smart_Motion_Activity_Is_Selected_The_Values_Are_Valid()
{
     SomeViewModel vm = ViewModelHelper.CreateDefaultViewModel();
     ...
}
```